# How to extract part of a polygon in R?

Tags: r, plot, gis, polygon

I would like to create a map of Europe in R to plot some of my data. I have modified the code below (taken from: http://www.r-bloggers.com/provincial-map-using-gadm/) to give me a map of Europe. All is great except that the sliver of Russia along the Baltic disappears.

How can I extract that portion of the Russia polygon to maintain a true map of Europe?

```
library(sp)
library(raster)
## Download Map of the World ##
WorldMap <- getData('countries')

## Subset world map to European countries ##
EuropeMap <- (WorldMap[WorldMap$CONTINENT=="Europe" & WorldMap$COUNTRY != "Russia",])

## Plot map ##
plot(EuropeMap, bg = "dodgerblue", axes = T)
plot(EuropeMap, lwd = 10, border = "skyblue", add = T)
plot(EuropeMap, col ="green4", add = T)
grid()
box()
invisible(text(getSpPPolygonsLabptSlots(EuropeMap), labels = as.character(EuropeMap$COUNTRY), cex = 0.5, col = "white", font = 2))
mtext(side = 3, line = 1, "Map of Europe", cex = 2)
mtext(side = 1, "Longtiude", line = 2.5, cex = 1.1)
mtext(side = 2, "Latitude", line = 2.5, cex = 1.1)
text(40,30, "Projection: Geographic\nCoordinate System: WGS 1984\nData Source: GADM.org\nCreated by: Keith Larson", adj = c(0,0), cex = 0.7, col = "grey20")
text(-35, 75, "Calopteryx splendens", col="white", font=3, cex=1.5)
```

Comment: If you can pull out the "Russia" polygon data, you might be able to find its intersection with the border coordinates of your final map, and plot that new "sliver" polygon.  Alternatively, plot all of "Russia" and overplot the exterior of your map with a white rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple to extract that portion of the Russia polygon,just like choose the data that conform to our condtions. For example:

```
datamapSliver <- datamap[datamap$Sliver==1,]
plot(datamapSliver)
```